# Input Value is set and visible but not accessible in another script

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason  if I put **script 1** under **script 2**  Script2 is  not able to access the **mydate input value**   I have an alert in  script  2that helps me test if the value is received. If I manually input a value into the **<input value"">** then it appears in my alert. I appreciate any help as this is baffling me. Thanks.

The process is script 1 sends the date to the input.   Then script 2 takes the date from the input.  Script 1  simulates  a result from ajax request.

```
<div class ="card"><input type="text" class="mydate" value=""></div>
```

**Script 1  sets the value**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.card').find('.mydate').val("Jan 5, 2022 15:37:25");
});
</script>
```

**Script 2  Alert is for troubleshooting contents**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var input =  $('.card').find('.expiredate').val();
 alert(input);
});
</script>
```

Comment: try to put your code in a "$(document).ready(function(){" closure.

Comment: This code can easily be turned into a runnable stack snippet.  Please do so.  What is the name of the variable that is not "accessible" ? mydate, input, counDownDate, distance, demo or something else? Use console.log to output each variable until you find the one that you can't read.  Where is your $(document).ready(function()  in script 2?

Comment: this is because script 2 run before script 1. Add a console.log before  each `$('.card').find('.mydate')...` to verify that.

Comment: Thanks  @jqueryHtmlCSS,  You gave me good advice and you hit the nail on the button with- $(document).ready(function() in script 2.    That was the issue!   Thanks you very much!   Please present it as your answer so I can tick it.   Wawan you were close so thank you too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@wawan and @Mister Jojo is right. the code need to be in document ready function so they can be executed in right order. You were trying to reach 'mydate' in a wrong way too.

You can try this:

HTML

```
<div class ="card"><input type="text" class="mydate" value=""></div>
<div><input type="text" class="timer" value=""></div>
<div><span id="demo"></span></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.card').find('.mydate').val("Feb 23, 2021 15:37:25");
    var input = $('.card').find('.mydate').val();
    var countDownDate = new Date(input);
    var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    //Time of difference
   $('.timer').val(days + "d " + hours + "h "+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s" ).css("color", "black");

    // If the count down is finished, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

As you can check on the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xjohnatha/hq10ywkf/33/

**EDIT**

Some observations have to be declared to close this question:

- @wawan and @Mister Jojo is right by putting the code on document on ready (even using this on each JavaScript document);
- but can't use the order like your answer (script 1 below script 2) because the order doesn't match, the script 1 have to run first to set the value, and script 2 then to use the value setted.

Comment: Thank you for expanding on the subject and the illustration Johnatha Relvas!     It appears the only issue was not just the doc on ready as that fixed part of the issue.  Cheers!

Comment: the reason for script 1 was to immitate the date coming from another source e.g   the input field mydate is populated by lets say a ajax result.    Then the challange was reading/getting the input field mydate into the 2nd script the timer script.

Comment: So from script 1 to input  field mydate, then from input field mydate to script 2

Comment: I understand, but you can call the ajax from the document ready function too. The timer doesn't wait for the ready document all the time, it'll be a bad idea.

Comment: Yes I agree about the timer not waiting for the  ready document  thanks.

Comment: thank you Johnatha Relvas  you answered the 2nd half to my problem (You can't use the order like your answer: script 1 below script 2.).   except for the (Dor)  that is the answer I needed to hear.   My scripts are all below  my html.   My scripts below (ajax)populate the above html. So I did not see a problem with setting up something below  for something aboveThats How I thought as I am new to JS.  . .You have corrected me thank you

Comment: Lets close this one as.   if you put the Document on Ready (mention wawan and Mister Jojo) and (You can't use the order like your answer: script 1 below script 2.) as your answer please And I will tick it.  Thank you for all your effort!

Comment: I edited this answer with the new informations. You can choose as the solution. Or if you were meaning to post another, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer!  @Johnatha Relvas  was right script does not work when **script1** is below **script2** is because  **Script2**  reads  the input field  too soon before it contains the latest value sent by **script1.**
I tested it by adding a button as below. After page load I clicked it and the data was alerted.   My solution to this problem is to add a button click to collect the data after page load.  **. The point is the data is still accessible, but just using another method to access it**
Thanks to   @wawan and @Mister Jojo, yes the code needs to be in document ready function too.

```
<div class ="card"><input type="text" class="mydate" value=""></div>
```

```
<a id="test-btn" >Test button</a>
```

**script2**

```
<script >
$("#test-btn").click(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
var input = $('.card').find('.mydate').val();
 alert(input);
  }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

**script1**

```
<script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.card').find('.mydate').val("Jan 5, 2022 15:37:25");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the order like your answer: script 1 below script 2.
Just because the script 1 is setting the value, and script 2 is reading it.
If you set the the timer to check every second, it will get when the script 1 is already loaded. But you have to do a condition to do only when value of 'mydate' is different then empty/null.